How to paginate server data in Vuetify 1.5?
I'm trying to paginate the server side data in Vuetify 1.5. There are 4 records in the database. I can get the data for the first page of 3 entries, but I'm unable to display the total count (although response headers returns 4)  and pagination controls as expected. Having said that, I can't go the next page to display the 4th data as pagination is disabled for some reason. I tried to cross check the docs and I'm clueless on what needs to be done to get that fixed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The image below should be showing 1-3 of 4. Not sure why isn't showing.

I used postman and the pagination worked for page 0 (3 entries) and page 1 (single entry)
 <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :pagination.sync="pagination"
      :total-items="totalDesserts"
      :loading="loading"
      class="elevation-1"
      @pagination="onPaginationChanged">
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>

   pagination = {
     page: 1,
     rowsPerPage: 3
    };
    
     @Watch('pagination', { deep: true })
     onPaginationChanged () {
    if (new Date(this.toDate) >= new Date(this.fromDate)) {
      this.showDesserts()
    }
  }
  
    async showDesserts () {
    this.loading = true
    const { page, rowsPerPage } = this.pagination
    const params = `&page=${page - 1}&size=${rowsPerPage}`
    this.getDesserts(this.fromDate, this.toDate, params)
      .then((response) => {
        this.desserts = response.data
        this.totalDesserts = parseInt(response.headers['x-total-count'], 10)
        this.loading = false
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Failed to fetch data:', error)
        this.loading = false
      })
  }


totalDesserts must be declared in the data section of the component - otherwise it is not reactive.

@IVOGELOV I'm using vue-class-component. I've initialized within the class as totalDesserts: number = 0 and it should be reactive as long as it's initialized properly and modifying it directly per my opinion. I even added logs and got the totalDesserts count as 4.

At first, you need to install the Vueitify paginated datatable component in Vue.js, use the following command:
npm install vuetify-paginated-datatable
and then add the datatable component in your project's HTML template.
pagination = {
  page: 1,
  rowsPerPage: 3
};

@Watch('pagination', { deep: true })
onPaginationChanged() {
  if (new Date(this.toDate) >= new Date(this.fromDate)) {
    this.showDesserts()
  }
}

async showDesserts() {
  this.loading = true
  const { page, rowsPerPage } = this.pagination
  const params = `&page=${page - 1}&size=${rowsPerPage}`
  this.getDesserts(this.fromDate, this.toDate, params)
    .then((response) => {
      this.desserts = response.data
      this.totalDesserts = parseInt(response.headers['x-total-count'], 10)
      this.loading = false
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Failed to fetch data:', error)
      this.loading = false
    })
}

